# Create empty conda environment

Tags: python, anaconda

I can create a new conda environment, with program `biopython` with this:

```
conda create --name snowflakes biopython
```

What if I do not want to install any program? It seems I can not do that:

```
» conda create --name tryout
Error: too few arguments, must supply command line package specs or --file

You can specify one or more default packages to install when creating
an environment.  Doing so allows you to call conda create without
explicitly providing any package names.

To set the provided packages, call conda config like this:

    conda config --add create_default_packages PACKAGE_NAME
```

Comment: Usually you want to at least install python. If you do not even want a python version, you can cheat conda by manually creating an empty environment using `mkdir -p </path/to/your/anaconda/distribution>/envs/<env-name>/bin`

Comment: doesnt make sense to me. why can we not create a packageless env?

Comment: What exactly is created when an "empty environment" is created?

Comment: @cammil Not sure if this has changed in the newer versions of conda because when I create a new environment without specifying anything, it installs zero packages

    conda create --n my_env  ## creates my_env with 0 packages installed

But, when I specify a python version for example python=3.7 then it installs the basic dependencies.
    conda create --n my_env2 python=3.7
    source activate my_env2
    conda list ## list around 10 packages installed

Comment: When I create new environment, somehow there are already many pip packages already there. How can I avoid that? I want python but no other packages.

Answer (score 265, accepted):

You can give a package name of just "python" to get a base, empty install.

```
conda create --name myenv python
conda create --name myenv python=3.4
```

Comment: thanks. I'm not sure why this isn't front and center on the Anaconda package list page

Comment: this is incredibly useful, thanks a lot! I also updated my conda chetsheet to include and emphasize this (in case it's helpful to others: https://github.com/NeuronQ/cookbook/wiki/Python-Conda-cheatsheet )

Comment: I am on conda version 4.3.23 and "conda create --name myenv" creates a new environment with no packages, not even python. It uses python from conda root environment.

Comment: When I do this, conda installs libgcc mutex, setuptools, pip and wheel in the new environment, so not exactly "minimal" is it?

Comment: @Adrian that's about as minimal as possible if you actually want to *do* anything in that environment, like install other packages...

Comment: @joelion: Unfortunately, if you want to use the environment for reproducible builds, you actually want to have full control over the environment. So I might install setuptools & wheel manually - but I also might choose not to. With the current bevhavior, this is not possible.

Answer (score 64):

If you've created a `create_default_packages` block in your `.condarc` file, @joelion's answer will install those packages. If you don't want those, use the `--no-default-packages` flag. For example:

```
conda create --name myenv python --no-default-packages
```

Comment: When I am trying this, with python=2.7, it's installing several pkgs, like libgcc-ng, certifi, libstdcxx-ng, etc. How to avoid installation of these?

Comment: you cannot. Without this python will not work.

Answer (score 15):

This is how to create a truly empty (light) conda_env with 0 packages:

```
conda create --name myenv --no-default-packages
```

it will take a few seconds to create and finish.

Comment: Doesn't work, that command still preloaded it with tons of packages like `pylint` `scipy`, etc.

Comment: @Cardin No, absolutely not. This command will have no packages installed. You can check it by using `conda list`  you will see there is not packages.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/3AiDnyh okay, I think you're technically right. But OP's intention appears to be about pip packages, not conda packages. Because using joelion's answer (which is the accepted answer), it does create a conda env with minimal pip dependencies.

Comment: I think the context of this question was about how to create an empty conda env. (0 conda packages). And my answer was delivering that!

Comment: @Cardin so, I tried the accepted answer and I have attached a picture for the output is that what you called an `empty`? https://i.ibb.co/RTbcpTx/conda-env.png. Also `pylint` and `scipy` doesn't come preloaded with `conda create --name myenv --no-default-packages`, I think you are confusing thinks :).

Comment: Yes it does. I followed your command `conda create --name myenv --no-default-packages` and did a `pip show scipy` and `pip show pylint`. It is inside. My previous screenshot (https://imgur.com/a/3AiDnyh) also showed a bucketload of pip packages came along with it. Whereas the accepted answer had minimal pip packages (literally what was necessary to get conda and pip running).

Comment: I'll admit the OP's question is vague, but if he accepted that particular answer, it shows that he intended for minimal pip, and not minimal conda packages. `--no-default-packages` gives zero conda packages but more than 200 (!) pip packages. `python` gives 11 essential conda packages (including `python`, `setuptools`, `pip`, `wheel`, `setuptools`) and 5 essential pip packages. The magnitude doesn't compare at all.

Comment: @Cardin it does not make sense that a newly installed conda env comes with ~ 200 pip packages. If so how long it took to finish creating the conda env?? For me, it took less than a minute on a pure Linux machine with Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: Also are you sure that your `python path` is pointing to `my_env` python when you executed `pip list`? Also, you are using a Windows machine and things might get messy there, all of these things you need to make sure about before assuming anything. I wouldn't waste my time discussing something like that unless I am sure about what's going on.

Comment: You're right, it was pointing to `base` python in PATH env variables, instead of `my_env` python - that's why the pip packages were there. I'd wrongly assumed they did symlink cloning which was why i didn't catch on why 200 pip packages was that fast. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

To create an environment that is absolutely empty, without python and/or any other default package, just make a new folder in `envs` directory in your `Anaconda` installation (Anaconda3 in this example):.

```
~\Anaconda3\envs>mkdir empy_env
```

The first time that you activate this environment a directory named `Scripts` in Windows, `bin` in Linux, with a few batch files are created. At the time of this post this works for Anaconda version 4.3.30 both in Windows and Linux.

I have noticed that @cel has suggested the same thing in the first comment under the question, but obviously it hasn't got the attention it deserves!

Answer (score 3):

For Conda 2020.11 Linux, the following command will create an empty environment.

```
conda create --name your-env-name
```

Comment: note that this doesn't install python: you'll be using the system python until you `conda install python` or install something with python as a dependency.

Comment: [This earlier answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60875306/570918) should be preferred as more *complete*, since it proactively guards against any "default packages" a user (or their sysadmin) may have defined in a `.condarc` file.