# Package not found creating conda environment, but can't install it

Tags: r, anaconda, conda, miniconda

How do I resolve this?

```
balter@exalab3:~$ conda create -n r322 r=3.2.2
Fetching package metadata .........
Solving package specifications: .


PackageNotFoundError: Package not found: '' Dependency missing in current linux-64 channels:
  - r 3.2.2* -> r-base 3.2.2 -> libgcc

Close matches found; did you mean one of these?

    libgcc: libgd, libmagic

You can search for packages on anaconda.org with

    anaconda search -t conda libgcc

balter@exalab3:~$ conda list | grep libgcc
balter@exalab3:~$ conda install libgcc
Fetching package metadata .........
Solving package specifications: .


PackageNotFoundError: Package not found: '' Package missing in current linux-64 channels:
  - libgcc

Close matches found; did you mean one of these?

    libgcc: libgd, libmagic

You can search for packages on anaconda.org with

    anaconda search -t conda libgcc
```

Comment: Could you share output for: `conda info`

Answer (score 0):

Full disclosure, this doesn't directly solve the problem you listed (risking the downvote) but I think this workaround works for what I believe you want to do.

The tricky thing is that the **r** language is in a different [channel](https://anaconda.org/r). In particular, [this](https://anaconda.org/r/r) looks like the package that you want. Ideally, the `conda create` command could allow you to specify that channel but it doesn't look like that works. Instead, you can try creating an empty environment -- [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35860436/create-empty-conda-environment) seems like the recommended way -- and then do the install in that environment. In other words, you can try this:

```
conda create -n r322 python
source activate r322  
conda install --channel r r=3.3.2
```