# Create clean conda environment

Tags: python, jupyter, conda

I want to make a blank/empty conda environment, but the newly created environment seems to be picking up packages from root or other environments. I *have* installed these packages (eg `bedtools`, `bwa`, etc) on the system as root and also into other conda environments, but want to make a clean one (for reproducibility).

Is this expected behavior? How can I debug this?

I'm (trying to) following this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37216638/3294994

```
$ conda env create -n test-env python
$ source activate 
$ conda env export
name: test-env
channels:
- conda-forge
- biconda
- anaconda
- defaults
dependencies
...
python=3.6.2=0
bcftools=1.6=0
bedtools=2.26.0=0
bwa=0.7.15=1
...
picard=2.14=py36_0
...
```

Some information about the environment below:

```
$ conda info
Current conda install:

               platform : linux-64
          conda version : 4.3.27
       conda is private : False
      conda-env version : 4.3.27
    conda-build version : not installed
         python version : 3.6.1.final.0
       requests version : 2.14.2
       root environment : /home/obk/anaconda3  (writable)
    default environment : /home/obk/anaconda3/envs/tttest2
       envs directories : /home/obk/anaconda3/envs
                          /home/obk/.conda/envs
          package cache : /home/obk/anaconda3/pkgs
                          /home/obk/.conda/pkgs
           channel URLs : https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/main/linux-64
                          https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/main/noarch
                          https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/linux-64
                          https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/noarch
                          https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/r/linux-64
                          https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/r/noarch
                          https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/pro/linux-64
                          https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/pro/noarch
            config file : None
             netrc file : None
           offline mode : False
             user-agent : conda/4.3.27 requests/2.14.2 CPython/3.6.1 Linux/3.13.0-132-generic debian/jessie/sid glibc/2.19
                UID:GID : 1001:1001
$ conda deactivate
$ conda info
Current conda install:

               platform : linux-64
          conda version : 4.3.27
       conda is private : False
      conda-env version : 4.3.27
    conda-build version : not installed
         python version : 3.6.1.final.0
       requests version : 2.14.2
       root environment : /home/obk/anaconda3  (writable)
    default environment : /home/obk/anaconda3
       envs directories : /home/obk/anaconda3/envs
                          /home/obk/.conda/envs
          package cache : /home/obk/anaconda3/pkgs
                          /home/obk/.conda/pkgs
           channel URLs : https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/main/linux-64
                          https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/main/noarch
                          https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/linux-64
                          https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/noarch
                          https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/r/linux-64
                          https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/r/noarch
                          https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/pro/linux-64
                          https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/pro/noarch
            config file : None
             netrc file : None
           offline mode : False
             user-agent : conda/4.3.27 requests/2.14.2 CPython/3.6.1 Linux/3.13.0-132-generic debian/jessie/sid glibc/2.19
                UID:GID : 1001:1001
```

---

And as an aside, the original problem I'm having is as follows:

```
$ source activate test-env
$ conda install jupyter
Fetching package metadata ...........
Solving package specifications: .

UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be in conflict:
  - imagemagick
  - jupyter
  - python 3.6*
Use "conda info <package>" to see the dependencies for each package.
```

I'm guessing this is because the newly created environment `test-env` has packages in it already...

Comment: Can you try running `conda create -n test-env python` instead of `conda env create...`?

Comment: That worked! .. and I just realized I *wasn't* following the answer from that link, as you pointed out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a new env by typing `conda create -n vEnv python`

That will create a fresh environment. Btw this is the same as if you go into the GUI and hit the button create. So that env that you created will be placed under envs in the anaconda file available everywhere, so you can simply activate it by doing: `conda activate vEnv`

You can check the pip and conda packages (once you activate your environment) like this:
`pip list`
`conda list`

I hope it helps