# New conda environment installing every package on my computer? How to create a clean environment?

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

I want to create a fresh conda environment called `new-gooey_env`.

```
conda create --name new_gooey_env python=3.7
```

I get a notification that the following packages will be insatlled:

```
ca-certificates    pkgs/main/win-64::ca-certificates-2020.6.24-0
  certifi            pkgs/main/win-64::certifi-2020.6.20-py37_0
  openssl            pkgs/main/win-64::openssl-1.1.1g-he774522_1
  pip                pkgs/main/win-64::pip-20.2.2-py37_0
  python             pkgs/main/win-64::python-3.7.7-h81c818b_4
  setuptools         pkgs/main/win-64::setuptools-49.4.0-py37_0
  sqlite             pkgs/main/win-64::sqlite-3.32.3-h2a8f88b_0
  vc                 pkgs/main/win-64::vc-14.1-h0510ff6_4
  vs2015_runtime     pkgs/main/win-64::vs2015_runtime-14.16.27012-hf0eaf9b_3
  wheel              pkgs/main/win-64::wheel-0.34.2-py37_0
  wincertstore       pkgs/main/win-64::wincertstore-0.2-py37_0
  zlib               pkgs/main/win-64::zlib-1.2.11-h62dcd97_4
```

That's great. I install them and activate my new environment.

```
conda activate new_gooey_env
```

Now when I type `pip freeze`, I can see that basically every package on my computer has been installed into this new environment.

The output of `pip freeeze` in my new environment is about 100 packages.

How can I create a new environment with just the bare minimum packages?

I have already googled this problem and followed the instructions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35860436/create-empty-conda-environment), which doesn't work hence the question.

**Note** when I type `conda list` I only get the list of packages above.

So is pip freeze command correct? Is there also 100 packages in my new environment?

edit: On Windows.

Comment: Do you have other Pythons with the same version number on the PATH or PYTHONPATH? Conda tends to work as expected only when envs are properly isolated, i.e., no other instances leaking in through environment variables.

Comment: @merv I do not have anything python on the PATH. When installing anaconda it recommends not to add it to path and to use anaconda prompt only. So I followed the advice during installation.

Comment: Are you sure `pip` is the one in the env? I.e., have you checked `which pip` or `where pip`? Can you check some of the packages that are not supposed to be installed in your env to see where they are loading from? E.g., if `numpy`, then `python -c 'import numpy; print(numpy.__spec__)'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `pip freeze -l` .
The l stands for local .

`pip freeze` otherwise acts on all your environments as your virtualenv has global access. That is my best guess.

And no , your new environment doesn't have 100's of packages!

Comment: I just created a new environment and tried `pip freeze -l` and I still get a big list of 100 packages. Some of which I installed once to try out even a year ago. Must be some weird windows thing. Very annoying.

Comment: I get the same behavior on WSL2. Any ideas?