# How can I create a virtual environment in which there will be no python libraries

Tags: python, virtualenv

I want to have an empty virtual environment where there will be no python modules or libraries that had installed before. I use git bash for this. I create it and activate, but when I use pip list or pip freeze I see all the libraries I have on my PC. What do I do wrong? Thank you.

Here is a print screen, that shows my actions:

[image]

Comment: See this: `conda create --name myenv python --no-default-packages` if you want to use `conda`. Refer to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35860436/create-empty-conda-environment.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
python -m venv env_name_here
```

Then activate it & do pip freeze.