# No ImageTk in PIL package

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I've used pip install Pillow to install Pillow package.I can't find ImageTk attribute even after installing the Pillow.I am new to Python So can you guys please answer me a simple solution.

i want to import that way.->form PIL import Image,ImageTk

but i dont see ImageTK.
I have been uninstalling and reinstalling it but nothing special.

Comment: What error are you getting after importing module

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "icon.py", line 2, in <module>
    from PIL import Image,ImageTk
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PIL'

Comment: Are you working on same environment where you are installing and using that environment to import it

Comment: I think it might be a problem.What should I do and How can i fix this?

Comment: Go through this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35860436/create-empty-conda-environment) -> install library -> use that environment -> import module are  and you working in pycharm??

Comment: I am working in Vscode. I didn't get what you mean . Can you plz explain me about this or guide me some easy way.